# iPad orientation portrait only

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation, project-settings

> I set Project Summary > iPhone / iPod Deployment Info > Supported Interface Orientations to portrait only mode.

This work well on All simulatiors , iPad(iOS 5.1) and iPhone(iOS 6.1).

But after I upgrade iOS on iPad from 5.1 to 6.1.2 then

> The application running on iPad become landscape (left+right) mode at application start up.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try going to YourApp-Info.plist file in Supporting Files and make sure the proper orientations are set for both `Supported interface orientations` and `Supported interface orientations (iPad)`

Comment: after add portrait to Supported interface orientations. I got an error 
'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: guess you were missing the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`? but you got it to work it seems:) glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Add the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientation` into your *info.plist*, with a setting for each orientation you support.

Comment: supposed to be `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`