# Only portrait mode not working for iPad / Xcode / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I use only portrait mode for my App. Its working fine for iPhone. But on iPad there is also the landscape mode. But I also want only Portrait mode for iPad.
What should I do? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V1K7.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590272/how-do-i-disable-landscape-orientation-on-an-ipad-app
check this, there are basically two different params in your .plist file for iPhone & iPad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad orientation portrait only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405023/ipad-orientation-portrait-only)

Answer (score 3):

open your plist file like a source code

[image]

Delete in this 3 lines

[image]