# How to lock orientation in portrait for an iPhone SwiftUI app running on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI iPhone-only app with its orientation locked in portrait, which works great. However, when the same app is run on an iPad (in emulation mode; iPad is not a target) the lock has no effect: the UI rotates with the device, which is unintended as it breaks the UI. It fails in the simulator and on an actual device.

I can reproduce this issue using an empty SwiftUI project with only a single view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

**iPhone works as expected:**

[image: iPhone in portrait mode]
[image: iPhone in landscape mode]

**iPad does not respect orientation lock:**

[image: iPad in portrait mode]
[image: iPad in landscape mode]

I have the following in my Info.plist, but no success. The UI still rotates on the iPad.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Then I defined an AppDelegate. Still no success, the UI keeps rotating on the iPad.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
}

@main
struct orientationApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

What is interesting:

- When I enable iPad as a target the orientation lock works out of the box. However, I do not want to offer the app for the iPad. I just want to fix the UI for users who deliberately install iPhone apps on their iPad.
- When I test the AppDelegate approach on an iPhone it works even if I allow all device orientations in Info.plist, so it seems to do the right thing (just not on the iPad).

I'm using Xcode 12.5 and Swift 5.

Comment: Take a look to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046367/5575955

Comment: Thanks, Fabio, but I already did this. Like I wrote above, the only item I have for `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` in my Info.plist file is `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`. I already deleted the other 3—and still it does not work.

Comment: Do you also have the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key set in info.plist (without the "~ipad")? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, I got both:
`<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key><array><string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string></array>` and
`<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key><array>  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string></array>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Unticking `Supports multiple windows` solved the problem for me

Comment: Thanks, @i4guar, I don't understand why, but this does work, amazing!

Comment: @Dominik this will be because to support multiple windows you have to support all device orientations (I guess so they know you're ok with random sized windows basically)